# Laravel Two request value get decrement and insert in column

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm New in Laravel I controller trying to get decrement (subtract) two input request value and pass result in ( balance_amount ) column.

**example**

```
input price request       100
input paid_amount request  50
result balance_amount      50
```

**my Controller**

```
 public function pay(Request $request)
    {
$request['price'] = $request->price;  //PRICE $150
$request['paid_amount'] = $request->paid_amount; //PAID $100
$request['balance_amount'] = $request->balance_amount; //BALANCE $50
 
    Installment::create($request);   
           }              

  return redirect( )->with('success',' PAID SUCCESSFULLY');

    }
```

Comment: you substract `paid_amount` from `price` ?

Comment: I dont see `$pay_installment` declared anywhere within the `pay` method

Comment: what is the strucure of `installments` table

Comment: You are welcome, it would be great if you add more clarity. Like you substract what from what. And I would helps to see the structure of your table

Comment: @medilies i just tying to get ( price - paid_amount = balance_amount ) ,  ( 150- 100= 50 )

Comment: @medilies i think you get understood what i want

Comment: @medilies pls update your answer u removed your answer it worked for me thank you

Comment: I did restore it, does it solve the problem ?

Comment: @ medilies yes my problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public function pay(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'price' => ['integer',],
            'paid_amount' => ['integer',],
        ]);

        Installment::create(
            [
                'price' => $validated->price,
                'paid_amount' => $validated->paid_amount,
                'balance_amount' => $validated->price - $validated->paid_amount,
            ]
        );

        return redirect()->with('success', ' PAID SUCCESSFULLY');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

obviously, you shouldn't create model from the request, there is not point to do that, you cant use a new variable to store the data to be created;

```php
public function pay(Request $request){
    $sourceData = $request->only('price', 'paid_amount', 'balance_amount');
    //you can modify the $souceData variable as you want to custom the data you need to insert 
    Installment::create($sourceData);   
}
```